# Wordpress plugins are active but not checked in admin tool

Tags: php, database, wordpress, apache, ssl

Ok, so I have a big problem. Or at least an indication of a big problem. You see I went to create a dev version of a recently launched site. I copied all the files over to a new directory, created my apache entries, created a brand new database for it, and copied over that database.

Then I made sure to change the www.mysite.com entries to dev.mysite.com in the database. All of that looked good and I restarted apache. After running into some issues with the dev site I decided to back away for the night. I went to check the production site and it was suddenly down. So I removed the SSL entry in default-ssl in Apache and restarted Apache again and that was fine.

Then I went into admin and noticed that on the plugin page it bolds the active plugins. It gives an accurate count. And the plugins are working. But the checkbox next to each isn't showing checked.

So I thought that maybe I messed up the database on accident. So I just blew away the db and re-imported it really quick from the backup I made before all this started (about 30 minutes ago). And it looks the same. The site is working, but I am having problems with admin.

Does anyone have any advice? This is freaking me out a bit. I have never had a problem like this before with creating a dev site and never had Wordpress do crazy stuff like this before.

I will add that this is running the latest version of Wordpress and WooCommerce. It seems like the site is working. But this is leaving me very concerned about other issues.

Comment: What is admin tool? Is that additional plugin? Have you tried to update or reinstall your wordpress?

Comment: check for any plugin which is overriding admin defaults ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The checkbox next to my active plugins isn't checked either. I think this is normal. You check them yourself in order to apply bulk actions to multiple plugins at once (e.g. check three plugins and then use the bulk action dropdown to active all three at once).

Sorry if I've misunderstood your problem here.

Comment: Good lord, I am losing my mind. For some reason I could have sworn that they are supposed to be checked. I have been using Wordpress for years. Ugh, I am letting all this stress get to me I guess. You are right, I just checked one of my other sites on a different server. I am not sure what I am thinking.

Comment: Do I get the bounty ? ! I never got one before :)

Comment: I will give it to you for restoring my sanity (as much as that can be done).

Comment: Well I selected you as the winner. I believe that gives it to you.

Comment: Good luck with that sanity thing. I think it's overrated ;)

Comment: I think a crappy monitor at home has something to do with it too. It confused me as to what I was looking at. That and a severe lack of sleep.